# Django won't add the default language prefix in URL at startup

Tags: django, internationalization, language-translation, django-i18n

My issue is with a recent Django website ( url: h t t p s : // bucegipark. ro )  that should automatically add the language prefix when you access it (like for example going to this link), but it suddenly STOPPED doing that around a month ago and really cannot find the issue. I reset all language internalization settings twice. I should mention that with debug set to True it redirects to URL with language prefix just fine, the issue comes up in production.

When no prefix is shown after the URL, database info is not either loaded.
After starting the website, if I choose a language using the dropdown list I built, it redirects to that URL with chosen language prefix. It does the same when I click the brand logo which has the `{% url 'home' %}` URL attached to it and redirects to the homepage with the language prefix just fine.

So theoretically, the urls.py code works fine I guess, the problem lies in recognizing the default language when you first open the website.

Code below:

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
from django.conf import settings
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

load_dotenv(verbose=True)
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
if os.getenv('ALLOWED_HOSTS'):
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend(os.getenv('ALLOWED_HOSTS').split(','))

DEVELOPMENT = False
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'modeltranslation',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 'django.contrib.gis',#django gis activation
    #developer added libraries
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'ckeditor',
    'hitcount',
    'captcha',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    #user apps
    'users',
    'services',
    'payments',
    'geemap',
    ]
SITE_ID = 1
INTERNAL_IPS = [
    # ...
    "127.0.0.1",
    # ...
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pnb_main.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',

            ],
        },
    },
]
#
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyMemcacheCache',
        'LOCATION': os.getenv('CACHES_LOC'),
    }
}

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pnb_main.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/


TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Bucharest'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

USE_L10N = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ro', _('Română')),
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('de', _('Deutsch')),
)
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 1

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ro'
#==============EMAIL SETTINGS==========================
#-----test
# EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'
#-----production
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
#-----email credentials
EMAIL_PORT=os.getenv('EMAIL_PORT')
EMAIL_HOST=os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_USE_SSL=False
EMAIL_HOST_USER='contact@bucegipark.ro'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')

MESSAGE_TAGS = {
        messages.DEBUG: 'alert-secondary',
        messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
        messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
        messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
        messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
 }
# ============ django-resized settings ====================
DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_SIZE = [1920, 1080]
DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_SCALE = 0.5
DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_QUALITY = 75
DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_KEEP_META = True
DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_FORCE_FORMAT = 'WebP'
DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_FORMAT_EXTENSIONS = {'WebP': ".WebP"}
DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_NORMALIZE_ROTATION = True

#================django simple captcha======================
CAPTCHA_IMAGE_SIZE = (100,50)
CAPTCHA_BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#2eb872"
CAPTCHA_FOREGROUND_COLOR = "black"
#=====================LOGGING  ERORRS=========================
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'pnb_main.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'services': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'payments': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
#===================Default primary key field type
#================https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

main project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import handler404, handler500
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from services.sitemaps import *


sitemaps = {
    'blogpost':BlogPostSitemap,
    'attraction-category':AttractionCategorySitemap,
    'flora-category':FloraCategorySitemap,
    'flora':FloraSitemap,
    'wildlife':WildlifeSitemap,
    'wildlife-category':WildlifeCategorySitemap,
    'events': EventSitemap,
    'team': TeamSitemap,
    'static': StaticViewSitemap,

}
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
    path("robots.txt", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="services/robots.txt", content_type="text/plain"),),
    path('captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('', include('services.urls')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('tickets/', include('payments.urls')),
)
#------------add custom media path for production mode-----------
urlpatterns += re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
if settings.DEBUG==False:
    handler404 = "services.views.page_not_found"
    handler500 = "services.views.server_error"
else:
    pass
```

homepage view code

```
#========================home page=================================
def home(request):
    template = 'services/home.html'
    weather = scraped_data()
    captcha_form = CaptchaForm()
    context = {
        "weather": weather,
        "captcha_form": captcha_form
    }
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.POST.get('form-type') == "signin-form":

            #---------user login functions-----------
            user = None
            try:
                username = request.POST.get('signin-name')
                password = request.POST.get('signin-password')
                # user_check = User.object.get(username = username)
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    try:
                        login(request, user)
                        context['user'] = username
                        return redirect('.')
                    except Exception as e:
                        messages.warning(request, _("Warning! {e}"))
                        return redirect('.')
                else:
                    messages.warning(request, _("User does not exist!"))
                    return redirect('.')

            except (Exception, User.DoesNotExist) as e:
                messages.warning(request, _("Warning! {e}"))

        #--------------check if newsletter email exists already---------
        if request.POST.get('form-type') == "subscribe":
            newsletter_email = request.POST.get('subscriber')
            if newsletter_email:
                try:
                    duplicate = Subscriber.objects.get(email=newsletter_email)
                    if duplicate:
                        messages.warning(request, _("This email already exists in our database!"))
                        return redirect('home')
                except:
                    #-----------------------SAVE IN DATABASE----------------
                    sub = Subscriber(email=newsletter_email, conf_num=random_digits(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
                    sub.save()

                    #---------------------send confirmation email settings------
                    sub_subject = _("Newsletter Bucegi Natural Park")
                    from_email='contact@bucegipark.ro'
                    sub_message = ''
                    html_content=_("Thank you for subscribing to our newsletter! You can finalize the process by clicking on this <a style='padding:2px 1px;border:2px solid black;background-color:black;color:white;font-weight:500;text-decoration:none;' href='{}{}/subscription-confirmation/?email={}&conf_num={}'> button</a>.".format('https://www.bucegipark.ro/',request.LANGUAGE_CODE, sub.email, sub.conf_num))
                    try:
                        send_mail(sub_subject, sub_message, from_email, [sub], html_message=html_content)
                        messages.success(request, _("A confirmation link was sent to your email inbox. Please check!"))
                        return redirect('home')
                    except Exception as e:
                        messages.warning(request, e)
                        return redirect('home')


    #fetching data from the database and adding to context dict
    context.update({
        'attr_categ': AttractionCategory.objects.all(),
        'attractions': Attraction.objects.filter(featured=True),
        'current_date': datetime.date.today(),
        'reviews': Testimonial.objects.filter(status=True),
        'partners': Partner.objects.all(),
        })
    
    return render(request, template, context)
```

How to make django show language prefix at startup?